# Es pobible recuperar un archivo borrado con el comando -r en un servidor linux?

Tags: linux, archivo

Cometí un error muy grave. estaba editando el archivo crontab de mi servidor remoto, estaba como usuario root y resulta que escribí "crontab -r" en vez de "crontab -e" y sin previo aviso simplemtne se eliminó. Estube buscando información y resulta que los archivos borrados con el comando -r no se almacenan en algun lugar como la papelera de reciclaje o algo parecido. Estoy muy preocupado ya que ahi estan programadas las copias de seguridad y todos los scripts que mi hosting coloco. Ya me comunique con ellos y debo esperar respuesta de una persona especializado en un lapso de 24 a 48 horas, pero estoy muy procupado. Alguien ha tenido una experiencia similar? sera posible recuperar ese archivo?

Answer (score 2):

`crontab -r` elimina el único archivo que contiene los trabajos cron.

Entonces, si no hay una copia de seguridad, lo único que puedes hacer es:

- En RedHat / CentOS, si sus trabajos se han activado antes, puede
  encontrar el registro cron en `/var/log/cron`. El archivo te
  ayudará a reescribir el cron nuevamente.
- Otra opción es recuperar el archivo utilizando una herramienta de
  recuperación de archivos. Sin embargo, es menos probable que esto
  tenga éxito, ya que la partición del sistema suele estar ocupada y es
  probable que los sectores correspondientes ya se hayan sobrescrito.
- En Unbuntu / debian, si su tarea se ejecuta antes, intenta esto:
  `grep CRON/var/log/syslog`

Comment: en el archivo /var/log/cron solo se almacena lo del dia actual? porque solo me aparece lo de hoy 19 de mayo.

Comment: `cd /var/log
cat syslog.1 syslog | grep CRON` y si necesitas aun más `cd /var/log
zcat syslog syslog.4.gz syslog.3.gz syslog.2.gz | grep CRON`

Comment: que haria ese comando? segun tengo entendido mostraria el contenido de del archivo syslog.1 ubicado en el directorio /var/log, pero lo ejecute y no hizo nada.

Comment: @JulianProg lo que veo que, inteligentemente, Manuel trata de hacer es tratar de reconstruir el comportamiento de las tareas programadas a través de los registros que dejo en los archivos de `syslog`.

Comment: @JulianProg Como sugirió Manuel, trata de buscar en alguno de los archivos de `syslog`. Lo que hace `zcat` es descomprimir archivos `.gz` y enviar su contenido a la salida estandar, y esta se conecta con `grep` que busca la palabra `CRON` para las tareas que ya ejecutó.
Para revisar en todos los archivos `syslog` puedes usar `zcat /var/log/syslog* | grep 'CRON'` que es un complemento a lo que sugirió Manuel en su comentario.